# Meteor takes multiple times to make a successful database read

Tags: meteor

Say I have a helper that needs to return an article's title.

```
<template name="articleList">
    <span>{{title}}</span>
</template>

Template.articleList.title = function () {
   return Articles.findOne({author: "Billy Bob"}).title
}
```

I often get a 'Cannot read property title of undefined' error. So when I try to debug it like this

```
Template.articleList.title = function () {
   console.log(Articles.findOne({author: "Billy Bob"}))
}
```

The log will say

```
undefined
undefined
Object[0]
```

So it only works on the third time. I think it's probably bad code somewhere in my router or somewhere else, but I don't know what it is. Any suggestions?

Comment: it happens because in the beginning when you client is loaded for the first time, it doesn't have any data yet. Next time it will subscribe for a publication. And then it will start receiving data. Read more about knowing when a subscription is ready here: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe

Comment: So what you're saying is that it's something that can't be undone? Because it doesn't happen for all my helpers. Some helpers only need one attempt and others need two.

Comment: Your other helpers may be working with cursors from `find`, rather than documents from `findOne`.

Comment: I am saying it is a structured designed behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that the document is already loaded by your subscription. Try this:

```html
<template name="articleList">
    <span>{{title}}</span>
</template>
```

```js
Template.articleList.title = function () {
    var doc = Articles.findOne({author: "Billy Bob"});
    return doc && doc.title;
};
```

The reason is that if the client hasn't yet received the document over DDP, the `findOne` call will return `null`. You get an error when you try to call `null.title`.

Comment: So it's not something that can be fixed I guess

Comment: You just need to understand how Meteor works. Your subscriptions are loaded in the background over DDP. This is what allows you to use the synchronous client-side collection interface, rather than having a bunch of async callbacks. When you use `findOne`, you need to remember that the associated result may not be loaded into minimongo yet. You can always do `find` with the `limit` option set to 1. This returns a reactive *cursor* rather than a *document*. You could also always do a custom server method call, but this will not be reactive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<template name="articleList">
    <span>{{article.title}}</span>
</template>

Template.articleList.article = function () {
   return Articles.findOne({author: "Billy Bob"});
}
```

Comment: I know that will work, but my question is more about why it takes three times to return a read.

Comment: @imslavko explained that in comment to your question